# Swift & iO8: keep overall screen rotation, but rotate sub elements?

Tags: ios, rotation, swift2

I want to be able to keep the general rotation of my view the same, when the phone is rotated, but rotate sub elements, but I am not sure how to about this? For clarity, something equivalent what the iPhone's camera app does, where the positioning of the main elements remains static, but the orientation of the icons change.

If I implement `shouldAutorotate()` to return false, then `viewWillTransitionToSize()` is never called (which makes sense), so I believe this should be left alone and the work should be done in another function?

Comment: http://benincosa.com/?p=3280